# Vite with Svelte does not include images in "dist" folder

Tags: svelte, vite

Should be a simple one I hope. I have a bite project that uses the Svelte template. When I run "npm run dev" my website displays correctly. However, when I run "npm run build" and then preview it no images display, they were not included in the "list" folder. I'm assuming I need to setup some configuration in the vite.config.js file?

Comment: Please provide a minimally reproducible example using stackbliz

Comment: All good Tachibana, see my answer below. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Ok, simple solution that I overlooked. I had placed all my assets in the "src/assets" folder of the project. Vite will not need this when building the "dist" version, instead place the assets into the "public" folder and reference the images, etc. as if they were in the root directory, i.e., from  "<image src='/src/assets/image.png'" to "<image src='image.png'".

Comment: that's too bad vite won't bam them and pack them for cache

Comment: Would not recommend this for most assets. The files in static will not be hashed.

Answer (score 1):

Your images should be in the `lib` folder and be imported before being used (see [Asset handling](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/assets))

```html
<script>
  import logo from '$lib/assets/logo.png';
</script>

<img alt="The project logo" src={logo} />
```

And the static images (favicon, ...) should be in the `static` folder (see [Project structure](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/project-structure))

Comment: Hi Cyril, thanks for your reply. I have a lot of images so it does not make much sense to import this way just JS.

Comment: @bennythemink In this case I think you should use [svelte-preprocess-import-assets](https://github.com/bluwy/svelte-preprocess-import-assets) which will import the images automatically